# showing blank format page without product details

Tags: php, mysql

i got a project which is based on warranty info of their product i created MySQL DB and inserted data and able to get data in prescribed format also and it's working fine

now the problem is if Warranty card number exists it is showing product info it's ok but if not exists it is showing blank format page without product details that is the problem.

i need to return page if data not exists or echo like check waranty card number

plz help

http://sagemax.in/wcheck.html

w c nuo. : LP8200FA

for refeance

code on Main Page

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="cased.php">
  Warranty Number <input type="text" name="search"> <br><br>
  <input type="submit"  value="submit">
</form>
```

Code on cased.php page

```
    <?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','aa_admin','aaaaaa') or die ("Couldn't connect to server."); 
$db = mysql_select_db('sagemax_case', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database."); 

$warno=$_POST['search'];

$data = 'SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE `warno` = "'.$warno.'"';
  $query = mysql_query($data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error());
      $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);?>
{
Warranty Number :</td><td class="txtcssleft"><?php echo $data2['warno'] }?>
```

actually their is 2 pages one is form page and other is warranty info page i need to check details before going to warranty page if details available only if details are not available it should be in same page. please check actual link on site it's live

i tried like

```
$data = 'SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE `warno` = "'.$warno.'"';
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
     header( "Location: cased.php" )
}else{
    //We have no results and can't find the warranty, return a different page saying no warranty results exist
    header( "Location: wc.php" )
```

but no use please help

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add an If statement to check if you get results back or not.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    //We have results, return formatted page here
}else{
    //We have no results and can't find the warranty, return a different page saying no warranty results exist
}
```

Comment: ok if results found i need to take them to other page if results are not available it should desply no results found plz check like that

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have rows before rendering anything to the page with the following. If no rows are returned by your query, echo or redirect as necessary.

@Aidan beat me, and his solution will also work. Mine just omits the >0.

```
session_start(); // You need this to use session variables. Add it to the destination page also. 

if(mysql_num_rows($query))
{
    // Updated the following to account for OP's comment.

    $_SESSION['data2'] = $data2; // This supposes that you session_start();

    // Do what you're currently doing if a row is returned.
}
else
{
    // There are no rows returned.
    echo "What, dude, no rows! Check your warranty card!";
}
```

If you want to pass the results to a new page,

Comment: ok if results found i need to take them to other page if results are not available it should desply no results found plz check like that

Comment: i tried this but no use   $data = 'SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE `warno` = "'.$warno.'"';
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
     header( "Location: cased.php" )
}else{
    //We have no results and can't find the warranty, return a different page saying no warranty results exist
    header( "Location: wc.php" )